# AppSync+ DynamoDB: The provided key element does not match the schema (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException;

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

How to map the Number type field to AppSync table schema? 
We have a dynamo table with Number type filed (as Primary partition key). In AppSync console, when we create API via "Import DynamoDB table", i have tried

(1) mapped to String/ID:  we can Scan but GetItem does not work. Both will give error message:

> The provided key element does not match the schema (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 4PA6K11N026Q9O2AOJ408PSUHNVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)

(2)mapped to int:  both Scan but GetItem do notwork. Scan will give error message:

> Can't serialize value (/listInstruments/items[0]/instrumentPermId) : Expected type 'Int' but was 'Long'

And GetItem will give error message:

> Validation error of type WrongType: argument 'instrumentPermId' with value 'IntValue{value=192760238682}' is not a valid 'Int' @ 'getInstrument'

Could anyone suggest?

Comment: In your ddb table, do you have both primary and sort key defined? If so, you might have to define both according to the [doc here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html).  Also, it would be good if you could give your example request mapping templates.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response @Lisa M Shon. And yes, we use both primary and sort key. And we provide both in the request mapping templates. Take "map to ID "for an example: here is the request template: 
```{
  "version": "2017-02-28",
  "operation": "GetItem",
  "key": {
    "instrumentPermId": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.instrumentPermId),
    "sourceCode": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.sourceCode),
  },
}```

Comment: here is the queries: ```query listInstruments {
  listInstruments {
    items {
      instrumentPermId
      sourceCode
    }
  }
}

query getInstrument {
  getInstrument(instrumentPermId:"192760238682", sourceCode:"1"){
      instrumentPermId
      sourceCode
    
  }
}```

Comment: query listInstruments will get :```{
  "data": {
    "listInstruments": {
      "items": [
        {
          "instrumentPermId": "192760238682",
          "sourceCode": "1"
        },
        {
          "instrumentPermId": "1",
          "sourceCode": "1"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}```

Comment: but query getInstrument will get :```{
  "data": {
    "getInstrument": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      ...
      "data": null,
      "errorType": "DynamoDB:AmazonDynamoDBException",
      "errorInfo": null,
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 24,
          "column": 3,
          "sourceName": null
        }
      ],
      "message": "The provided key element does not match the schema (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 7AUFUVA761KDSVTUTSEF34CAA7VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)"
    }
  ]
}```

Comment: Is there anything i am wrong or have missed?

Comment: Is instrumentPermId the primary key?  What is the sourceCode?

Try it with if instrumentPermId is the primary key:

`{ "version": "2017-02-28", "operation": "GetItem", "key": { "instrumentPermId": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.instrumentPermId) } }`

Comment: instrumentPermId (Number) is the Primary partition key, and sourceCode (String) is the Primary sort key.  Both mapping templates below do not work:(1) `{
  "version": "2017-02-28",
  "operation": "GetItem",
  "key": {
    "instrumentPermId": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.instrumentPermId)
  },
}` (2) `{
  "version": "2017-02-28",
  "operation": "GetItem",
  "key": {
    "instrumentPermId": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.instrumentPermId),
    "sourceCode": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.sourceCode),
  },
}`

Comment: What's the error message you get when you try it with my suggestion?